# SpringBoot 2.6.3 not binding @ConfigurationProperties on List of Objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I know this must be simple, and I've seen multiple similar questions, however my entire setup seems to be ok (as solutioned in the other posts), yet this problem persists.

Here's my setup

**Environment**

- Spring Boot `2.6.3`
- Java `17`

**application.yml**

```
platforms:
  configs:
    - platform: ABC
      base-url: https://some-url-01.com/api
      description:
      logo:
    - platform: DEF
      base-url: https://some-url-02.com/api
      description:
      logo:
```

**Config Properties**

```
@Data
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "platforms")
public class PlatformProperties {

    private final List<PlatformConfig> configs = new ArrayList<>();

    @Data
    public static class PlatformConfig {
        private final Platform platform;
        private final String baseUrl;
        private final String description;
        private final String logo;
    }
}
```

**Platform.java** - a simple enum

```
public enum Platform {
    ABC, DEF
}
```

**Configuration**

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(PlatformProperties.class)
public class ClientConfig {

    private final PlatformProperties platformProperties;

    
    @PostConstruct
    public void showProperties(){
        platformProperties.getConfigs().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

This entire setup seems perfectly fine (Ref: [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.enabling-annotated-types)), however `platformProperties.getConfigs()` is always empty because there was no binding on `platforms.configs` as defined from the `application.yml`

I have a similar setup on a different project (`springboot 2.5.7` / `Java 8`) where everything works exactly as expected.

What about this setup/configs is wrong???

Comment: I have seen lombok getting in the way. So, you might try removing that. Just a suggestion.

Comment: If you Autowire `Environment environment;`, could you validate that your properties exists in there with `environment.getProperty(...)`?

Comment: Does it work if you remove `@ConstructorBinding` from `PlatformProperties`? `@Data` includes `@RequiredArgsConstructor`. In this case, this yields a no-args-constructor as the only field `configs` is assigned a value and thus not "required".

Comment: Sorry folks for coming back to this quite late. Thank y'all for all the suggestions, but I posted the answer that worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yah, I solved this a long time ago, just wanted to provide the answer, and it was quite simple too.

You see this line?

```
private final List<PlatformConfig> configs = new ArrayList<>();
```

That was the culprit.

Notice that the `configs` variable is final and was already assigned a `new ArrayList<>()` as it's value, hence it was immutable.

Solution was to remove the initial assignment so the line became;

```
private final List<PlatformConfig> configs;
```

The constructor binding went OK and the `configs` values were populated as expected.

Comment: So who's downvoting without providing context? ... 

Looks like S/O needs to consider ensuring that the downvotes enforce provision of context (e.g via comments). ... And perhaps, should the downvoter be wrong, an option to correct them, so as not to misguide others.

Without these, there's no learning opportunity from downvotes - neither for the poster, the downvoter, nor the audience.

Comment: You're solutions seems correct and I agree with your comment. +1